# Replace first row in specific columns with 0

Tags: python, pandas

I want to replace the first row of two columns with `0`. I can achieve this by returning a new `df`. But it doesn't work when changing `inplace = True`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({   
    'Code1' : ['A','A','B','B','C','C'],    
    'Code2' : [np.nan,np.nan,5,np.nan,np.nan,10],                      
    'X' : [np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,3],    
    'Y' : [np.nan,np.nan,2,np.nan,np.nan,4],                                   
    })


df.loc[:0, 'X':'Y'].replace(np.nan, 0, inplace = True)
```

Intended Out:

```
  Code1  Code2    X    Y
0     A    NaN  0.0  0.0
1     A    NaN  NaN  NaN
2     B    5.0  1.0  2.0
3     B    NaN  NaN  NaN
4     C    NaN  NaN  NaN
5     C   10.0  3.0  4.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `df.loc[..,..]` you return a copy of a `df` and then you replace your values "inplace" of this copy, which have no effect on the origial df.

Your code is fine, just set directly to zero instead of using `.replace`

```
df.loc[:0, 'X':'Y'] = 0
```

```
  Code1  Code2    X    Y
0     A    NaN  0.0  0.0
1     A    NaN  NaN  NaN
2     B    5.0  1.0  2.0
3     B    NaN  NaN  NaN
4     C    NaN  NaN  NaN
5     C   10.0  3.0  4.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Direct assignment with `loc` works

```
df.loc[0, 'X':'Y'] = 0.00
```

Comment: overlooked. fixed :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use `at` to select single elements and replace them inplace:

```
df.at[0, "Code2"] = 0
```

Or you could change them together like this:

```
df.loc[0, ["X", "Y"]] = 0
```

Comment: Or just `= 0`, since a single value broadcasts to whatever shape you have on the left hand side

Comment: @rafaelc thanks! Do you wanna edit it on the answer?